# Configuring AIX auditing for rmdir and syslog collection

Tags: aix, syslog, audit

How can the auditing feature in an AIX Unix system be configured to collect information about the removal of a directory (though `rmdir`) and send it to syslog?

Comment: What if we need to audit any user that removes a directory. Not a specific user

Answer (score 0):

Try this (`#` implies escalated privileges):

```
# smit syslog # install syslog

# chuser audit=true <user you wish> # enable auditing

# echo "rmdir:fac=AUE_RMDIR:lo=none:hi=none" >> /etc/security/audit/config

# startsrc -s auditd # start the daemon

$ rmdir some-dir

# grep AUE_RMDIR /var/log/syslog.log # check if info was collected
```